# Non-english characters are not displayed in markdown

Tags: r, markdown

I am writing a report in polish language in markdown in R (.Rmd extension). Unfortunately I can't desplay polish characters likes `ą`, `ę` and so on neither in `html` nor `pdf` output.

My session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250    LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] markdown_0.7.7 httr_1.0.0     knitr_1.10.5  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] R6_2.1.0         magrittr_1.5     formatR_1.2      htmltools_0.2.6  rstudioapi_0.3.1 curl_0.9.1       yaml_2.1.13      stringi_0.5-5    rmarkdown_0.7   
[10] jsonlite_0.9.16  stringr_1.0.0    digest_0.6.8     evaluate_0.7
```

Some reproducible example

```
---
title: "Review"
author: "My name"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
geometry: margin=2cm
---

## Wstęp

Media społecznościowe ...
```

All special polish characters are displayed as corresponding english character so the output is like this

```
Wstep

Mecia spolecznosciowe ...
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is the encoding used to save the .Rmd file? If not yet, I suggest UTF-8.

Comment: In global options default text encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem with html output. Polish characters are displayed for me correctly but in another font. Polish is my OS default language if it's important.

Comment: Thank you @Ardavel. So I have no idea what the problem is...

Comment: In my LaTeX preemble, I always use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.